# Input and button in same line with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to put an input field and a Button in the same line. I want to set fix size for the button, and and I want the form to fill the available space. I've tried to create my own solution, but unfortunately the button is lower than the input field. How can I fix this?

[image]

CSS:

```
.input-bar {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-bar-item {
    display: table-cell;
}

.input-bar-item > button {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.width100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="input-bar">
    <div class="input-bar-item width100">
      <form>
         <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control width100">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="input-bar-item">
      <button class="btn btn-info">MyButton</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/5clqg067q4DiMHRkoPEY?p=preview

Comment: This may help Bootstrap [Button Addons](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons).

Comment: For Bootstrap 4 see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522299/171456

Answer (score 57):

There's a couple of things you can do. One is use inline forms, another is using input groups and an `input-group-btn`. Here is a plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/BNPRY0NL1G1fP7s24mFM?p=preview

My preference is the `input-group-btn`

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control width100">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-info">MyButton</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct. It is by far the easiest solution and it is the bootstrap way of doing it

Comment: @OutofOrbit When you see a good answer always upvote the one who posted it first.

Comment: @OutofOrbit tell that explicitly to `user1552545` to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 10):

Here is your answer: 
Group on the left Side

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Group on the right side:

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "form-inline" class made by bootstrap

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" value="button" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this

```
<div class="input-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" >
     <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
     </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation at http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups, you can do this with in house Bootstrap CSS:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your text field..."> <-- Text field
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Your button</button> <-- Inline button
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope I can help!