# Bootstrap / CSS - Input, button and select in the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put an input, a button and a select in the same line using bootstrap/css, but the **select**, depending on its content size, is going to the next line, as follow. What can I do?

[image]

Here is the part of the HTML:

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="ClienteBusca.value" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" v-on:click.prevent="buscarCliente" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="selectedCliente">
            <option v-for="cliente in Clientes" v-bind:value="cliente">{{cliente.nome}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, here is the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/taianrj/r81tqbm9/1/

Comment: Your `select` should be nested within the same `input-group` as the other inputs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with `form-inline` is that it's applying `width:auto;` on the select and as in your scenario content is large and enough space is not available in the first line so it's starting from the new line. Instead of using form-inline you can restructure your markup like that:

```
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectedCliente">
                            <option>test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
                                test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
                                test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
                            </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the latest Bootstrap 4.1 (not alpha), and switch the `form-inline` to `d-flex`...

```
           <div class="d-flex">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="ClienteBusca.value" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" v-on:click.prevent="buscarCliente" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" id="selectedCliente">
                            <option v-for="cliente in Clientes" v-bind:value="cliente">test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
           </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/fjZ7U8tbIH

Comment: Use padding or margins.. for example `<div class="form-group pr-1">` on the first group.